# Recommendations for Internet access control software for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, access-control

We are using [`Microsoft Security Essentials`](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/) for virus and malware protection.

It seems the parental controls on Windows 7 control access to certain programs (games, browsers) at particular times, but would not necessarily restrict which sites a user could visit.

What are the recommendations for software to control access to "restricted sites" or those that may be deemed inappropriate for young Internet users on a Windows 7 machine? Does Microsoft provide a solution (like Security Essentials)?

Comment: IMHO, the best "parental controls" are the parents themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dan's Guardian](http://dansguardian.org/) and [OpenDNS Family Shield](http://www.opendns.com/familyshield) are two popular free solutions.  Dan's Guardian is less user friendly but more powerful, OpenDNS is appealing because it's so easy to use.

I haven't used it, but [Microsoft Live Family Safety](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Protecting-your-kids-with-Family-Safety) might be exactly what you're looking for.

For ultimate control you could set up your own proxy, but that may be more work than you're looking to invest.

Answer (score 1):

It is Best to be done at the router/modem level, after configuration change the routers default password.

Software is too easy for kids to get past.

[Router that can control when internet is on/off, based on time ranges?](https://superuser.com/questions/169901/router-that-can-control-when-internet-is-on-off-based-on-time-ranges)

.

The [DLink DIR-655](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LIFB7S) has this capability right out of the box, your router/modem (if you have one) may already have this capability.

Edit your post to include the model of your router or modem if you are using one.

Answer (score 0):

Much information is available about this question. See the following articles.

[Best Free Parental Filter](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-parental-Filter.htm)
Discusses OpenDNS, Norton Safety Minder, K9 Web Protection, Windows Live Family Safety.

[Internet Filter Software Review](http://internet-filter-review.toptenreviews.com/)
Discusses Net Nanny Parental Controls, PureSight PC, CYBERsitter, Safe Eyes, CyberPatrol, McAfee Family Protection, FilterPak, imView.

[Parental Control Software: Reviews](http://www.consumersearch.com/parental-control-software)
Discusses Net Nanny, CyberPatrol Parental Controls, OnlineFamily.Norton, Safe Eyes.