# How to limit internet access time per mac address

Tags: wireless-router, mac-address, parental-controls

I want to be able to limit the amount of time some devices can connect to the internet to one hour per day. As an added bonus, I would like to restrict some sites (or categories of sites) per MAC address.
Is that possible to do using only a router (and how?) or do I need something more?

Comment: Product recomendations are off-topic. Anyways what you need is a proxy to control access (or time of access) and restrict sites (usually per IP but you can always assign the IP you want to the MAC addresses in your dhcp and block the others). Proxies can be found in some routers but usually they are very limited.

Comment: Are you looking for a Captive Portal?

Comment: Obs: edited to remove the product recomendation part but have a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/169901/router-that-can-control-when-internet-is-on-off-based-on-time-ranges?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

if you speek about a real (osi level 3)router -> NO then you need a firewall.

But if you mean a Multifunction Home Router Thingy like the Zyxel NBG 416 (http://www.brack.ch/zyxel-nbg-416n-wlan-router-170007) the there is in most of all times a firewall integrated.

Then you should have a look at the firewall settings on that divices manual.